# Is it safe to assume 64-bit counter doesn't suffer from overflow?

Tags: cpu, identity

32-bit counters overflow fast.

128-bit space is considered "infinite" (should exceed life of the Universe, so used as UIDs).

What about 64-bit counter? Are they practically "infinite"? Can one use them for assigning DB IDs?

Comment: Why shouldn't they run full in the same way, but slower?

Comment: That depends on how many IDs you need. 2^64 ~ 2*10^19, that should last for a while ... Ie, if you generate 1000 Ids in every second, you will roughly need 600.000.000 years for a overflow.  But of course if you need more, you will have an overrun at some time ...

Comment: @derpirscher The number is quite large, I have feeling that no company exhausts 64-bit IDs even if it assigns unique numbers to every product/document/event/etc.